# How to use scss parent selector to select its double selector

Tags: css, sass

I came threw a scenario where I wanted to reference to my parent selector in my sass, later instance I wanted to add the parent selector its double selector `animate` to perform a certain animation on scroll. Is there a way I can achieve it. Any help would be appreciated. I know it's tricky to explain my question. Hopefully below example explains my need.

**CSS**

```
.parent--selector.animate .child-selector {
  opacity: 1;
}
.parent--selector .child--selector {
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

I wanted to achieve the above styles using scss with the below pattern

**SCSS**

```
.child--selector {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  .parent--selector & {
    &.animate {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear, but I think I understood you correctly.

Rules must be written in parallel ...

```
.parent--selector {
  &.child--selector.animate {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &.parent--selector {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

If you show your html I will say more precisely, if of course I was mistaken in this example and did not understand correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo SCSS there doesn't quite make sense as this would yield something like:

```
.child--selector{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
} 

.child--selector .parent--selector.animate{
 opacity: 1;
}
```

You wouldn't be able to have the `.child--selector` as a parent in SCSS but expect it to be a child selector in CSS, in short, it wouldn't be possible.

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want to achieve, but you could maybe try using something in SASS called `@extend`

The basic idea would be have to the parent selector outside the .child--selector like this:

```
  .parent--selector & {
    &.animate {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

And then reference it inside the child--selector like this

```
.child--selector {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;

  @extend .parent--selector;
}
```

Helpful article regarding @extend:
https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/

You can achieve a similar outcome using mixins: 
https://sass-lang.com/guide